# AFAmazonS3Manager specify image download dimensions

Tags: ios, image, amazon-s3, photo, afnetworking-2

I'm using AFAmazonS3Manager to upload and download images from my S3 instance. Is there any way to specify the image dimensions prior to download so that I don't need to download full-sized images if only a thumbnail is needed? Previously, I was storing images on my EC2 server, so that I was able to resize and even crop images before returning them to the iOS end, making it so I would only return the size I necessary for the given iPhone (e.g. 5 vs. 6) and context. However, I can't figure out how to do it when images are stored on S3.

Comment: Have you considered caching a copy of the image for each of the dimensions you wish to retrieve?

Comment: @IanMacDonald I've considered it but that seems a bit wasteful - I'll need 2-3 dimensions for each size of iPhone. Is that the best way to do it though?

Comment: Generally speaking, space is cheaper than computational power. Imagine your app becomes the next Twitter, boasting millions of users. If each one of those users needs to request the same resized image, you're going to be paying through the nose for all that processor time to do the same operation over and over again. Just store the images statically if they are static.